# Animated model exported from Blender won't animate in SceneKit

Tags: ios, animation, scenekit, blender

I'm trying to import an animated model exported from Blender, but I'm having trouble animating it in SceneKit.

What I've tried:

1. I run that animation inside Blender and it worked (= The original animation data must be OK).
2. In my SceneKit project I imported another dae model which is included Apple's SceneKit example and saw it worked. (= SceneKit + Collada works OK)
3. Baked the animation in Blender with "Bake action" and then export, which didn't work
4. Read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41130425/scenekit-load-node-with-animation-from-separate-scn-file) SO topic and tried this way of adding animation, which didn't work

   ```
   [childNode enumerateChildNodesUsingBlock:^(SCNNode *child, BOOL *stop) {
   for(NSString *key in child.animationKeys) {               // for every animation key
       CAAnimation *animation = [child animationForKey:key]; // get the animation
       animation.usesSceneTimeBase = NO;                     // make it system time based
       animation.repeatCount = FLT_MAX;                      // make it repeat forever
       [child addAnimation:animation forKey:key];            // animations are copied upon addition, so we have to replace the previous animation
   }
   ```
5. Tried "Automated Collada Converter" introduced in the same SO topic, didn't work as well
6. Checked [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10592/collada-export-doesnt-preserve-animation-for-all-bones) topic and made sure which options to check when baking the action. No luck

Are there anything else to check? Any information is welcome, even didn't work in your place.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the animation play in macOS Preview app?