# Adding animation to an 3d model via ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, animation, 3d, arkit

I have a 3d model of a human being standing. I implemented it into an project using arkit and can place it somewhere in the room. So far so good, but I would like to add an animation to the 3d model. For example when I press the `buttonDance` that it starts dancing. Not to move it up and down, but to add an animation to it.

What are keywords to make this work or does anyone have a brief way of doing this? Maybe what software to use or is it possible within `sceneKit` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You can use services such as [Mixamo](https://www.mixamo.com/) to generate an animation for your character.

I would advise you to use 3D models in Collade (.DAE) format because this format includes all your animations inside. You will have to clean the .DAE file to collect all the bone animations into one animation, [more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24539607/how-can-i-export-dae-files-for-use-in-scene-kit-without-seeing-untitled-animati/24924702#24924702).

You will then need to read the animation from the .DAE file and add it to the node (your 3D model). [Esteban Herrera has a great blog post](https://blog.pusher.com/animating-3d-model-ar-arkit-mixamo/) on how to animate 3D models with ARKit.